# Mysql query compare column name with some value

Tags: mysql

I need mysql query where I need to find which column name have same value as variable value and not null, here is a table:

```
id | registration | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat4 
-----------------------------------------------
1  | abcdefgh123  |  x   |  x   |  null|   x   
2  | 123rft543hz  |  null|  x   |   x  | null   
3  | gfzhafduqgu2 |  x   |  x   |   x  |  null
------------------------------------------------
```

query need to be something like:

```
$temp = 'cat2'; // it's dynamic

SELECT registration FROM my_table WHERE column_name LIKE '$temp' AND $temp NOT NULL;
```

I dont know how to use column_name in mysql query, is any reserved word for that? Not using exactly one, I need to use generic column_name, to comparing with my variable $temp?

Thanks!

Comment: This kind of problem is often indicative of poor design. See normalization.

Comment: Just use your temp value as column name: `SELECT registration FROM my_table WHERE $temp NOT NULL;`